# ERROR: 'The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.'

Tags: java, html, pdf

Hi I am getting that error when converting html to PDF
Here is my html:

```
String html = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
            + "<html>"
            + "<head><style>"
            + "@font-face { "
            + "  src: url(arial.ttf); "
            + "  -fs-pdf-font-embed: embed; "
            + "  -fs-pdf-font-encoding: Identity-H;}"
            + "html *"
            + "{font-size: 11px;"
            + " font-family: Arial;}"
            + "</style></head>"
            + "<body>"
            + "<div id=\"logo\" class=\"media\" data-src=\"gsis.PNG\" style=\"width: 90px; height: 90px\" ></div>"
            + "<p style=\"text-align: center; line-height: 90%; \">Statement of Members Account</p>"
            + "<p style=\"text-align: center; line-height: 90%; \">Premium and Loan Account Balances Index</p>"
            + "<p style=\"text-align: center; line-height: 90%; \">As of "+ dateFormat.format(date) +"</p>"
            + "<br></br>"
            + "<table style=\"width: 100%;\">"
            + var1
            + "</table>"
            + "<br></br>"
            + "<hr></hr>"
            + "<br></br>"
            + "<p>This is the summary of your premium and loan account balances on record with GSIS as of "+ dateFormat.format(date) +"."
            + " To view a more updated summary and detailed account balances, you can go to "
            + "<span style=\"color: #0000ff; font-style: italic; text-decoration: underline;\">www.gsis.gov.ph</span> and log-on to eGSISMO."
            + "</p>"
            + "<p>In case of any discrepancy, please coordinate with your Personnel/Accounting Office to facilitate reconciliation of your record"
            + "and accounts with GSIS.</p>"
            + "<br></br>"
            + "I. PREMIUM ACCOUNT"
            + "<br></br>"
            + "<table border=\"1\" style=\"width: 100%; \">"
            + "<tr>"
            + "<td>Policy Type</td>"
            + "<td>Policy Number/Insurance Account</td>"
            + "<td>Due</td>"
            + "<td>Interest</td>"
            + "<td>Total</td>"
            + "</tr>"
            + var2
            + "</table>"
            + "<br></br>"
            + "<br></br>"
            + "II. LOAN ACCOUNT"
            + "<br></br>"
            + "<table border=\"1\" style=\"width: 100%; \">"
            + "<tr>"
            + "<td>Loan Type</td>"
            + "<td>Contract Account</td>"
            + "<td>Date Loan Granted</td>"
            + "<td>Gross Loan Amount</td>"
            + "<td>Monthly Amort</td>"
            + "<td>Total Repayment</td>"
            + "<td>Principal Balance</td>"
            + "<td>Interest/Surcharge</td>"
            + "<td>Outstanding Balance</td>"
            + "</tr>"
            + var3
            + "<br></br>"
            + "</table>"
            + "<br></br>"
            + "<br></br>"
            + "III. Period with Premium Payment (PPP)"
            + "<table cellpadding=\"10\" border=\"1\" style=\"width: 100%; \">"
            + var4
            + "</table>"
            + "<br></br>"
            + "<br></br>"
            + "LEGEND:"
            + "<br></br>"
            + "<p>A. Total Length of Service is the total number of years, months, days you are in government service.</p>"
            + "<p>B. Total Leave of Absence WITHOUT Pay (LWOP) is the period of time where no actual service was rendered "
            + "and paid. As such, premium payment for said period of time is not required. In which case, the period is not "
            + "considered in the computation of total length of service.</p>"
            + "<p>C. Actual Length of Service is the Total Length of Service less Total Leave of Absence WITHOUT Pay</p>"
            + "<p>D. Actual Length of Service WITH Posted Premium Payment (PPP) is the number of years in service"
            + " wherein correct premium payments have been paid and posted.</p>"
            + "<p>E. Actual Length of Service WITHOUT Posted Premium Payment (PPP) is the number of years in service "
            + "that do not have premium payments. This is subject to reconciliation with the member and agency record.</p>"
            + "<p>F. Equivalent Salary Based on Posted Premium Payment is the salary which had paid premium payment. This "
            + "salary will be used in the computation of gross loan amount.</p>"
            + "</body>"
            + "</html>";
```

Yeah more of wordings. I can't find any & in the whole html code. So where is this error coming?:

```
 ERROR:  'The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.'
org.xhtmlrenderer.util.XRRuntimeException: Can't load the XML resource (using TRaX transformer). org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.
```

var1

```
 String var1 = "<tr>"
            + "<td style=\"align: left; width: 80px; \">Name:</td>"
            + "<td colspan=\"4\" style=\"width: 60%;\">" + fullName + "</td>"
            + "</tr>"
            + "<tr>"
            + "<td style=\"align: left; width: 80px; \">Address:</td>"
            + "<td colspan=\"4\" style=\"width: 60%;\">" + address + "</td>"
            + "</tr>"
            + "<tr>"
            + "<td style=\"align: left; width: 80px; \">Agency:</td>"
            + "<td colspan=\"4\" style=\"width: 60%;\">" + agencyName + "</td>"
            + "</tr>"
            + "<tr>"
            + "<td style=\"align: left; width: 80px; \"></td>"
            + "<td colspan=\"4\" style=\"width: 60%;\">" + agencyAddress + "</td>"
            + "</tr>"
            + "<tr>"
            + "<td style=\"align: left; width: 80px; \">Date of Birth:</td>"
            + "<td style=\"width: 60%;\">" + dob + "</td>"
            + "<td style=\"align: left;\">CRN:</td>"
            + "<td>" + crn + "</td>"
            + "</tr>"
            + "<tr>"
            + "<td style=\"align: left; width: 80px; \">BP No:</td>"
            + "<td style=\"width: 60%;\">" + bp + "</td>"
            + "<td style=\"align: left;\">ID No:</td>"
            + "<td>" + id + "</td>"
            + "</tr>";
```

var2

```
String var2 = "<tr>"
            + "<td>" + policyType + "</td>"
            + "<td>" + policyNumber + "</td>"
            + "<td>" + personalShare + "</td>"
            + "<td>" + psLifeInterest + "</td>"
            + "<td>" + psTotal + "</td>"
            + "</tr>";
```

var3

```
String var3 = null;

        var3 += "<tr>"
                + "<td>" + loanType + "</td>"
                + "<td>" + contract + "</td>"
                + "<td>" + dateLoanGrancted + "</td>"
                + "<td>" + grossAmt + "</td>"
                + "<td>" + totAmortAmt + "</td>"
                + "<td>" + totRepaymentAmt + "</td>"
                + "<td>" + obPrincipalAmt + "</td>"
                + "<td>" + intSurAmt + "</td>"
                + "<td>" + obTotAmt + "</td>"
                + "</tr>";
```

var4

```
String var4 = "<tr>"
            + "<td style=\"width:10px;\">A</td>"
            + "<td style=\"width:60%;\">Total Length of Service (TLS) in Years</td>"
            + "<td>"+tls+"</td>"
            + "</tr>"
            + "<tr>"
            + "<td style=\"width:10px;\">B</td>"
            + "<td style=\"width:60%;\">Total Leave Of Absence Without Pay (LWOP) in Years</td>"
            + "<td>"+lwop+"</td>"
            + "</tr>"
            + "<tr>"
            + "<td style=\"width:10px;\">C</td>"
            + "<td style=\"width:60%;\">Actual Length of Service</td>"
            + "<td>"+als+"</td>"
            + "</tr>"
            + "<tr>"
            + "<td style=\"width:10px;\">D</td>"
            + "<td style=\"width:60%;\">Actual Length of Period WITH Premium Payment (PPP)</td>"
            + "<td>"+rcs+"</td>"
            + "</tr>"
            + "<tr>"
            + "<td style=\"width:10px;\">E</td>"
            + "<td style=\"width:60%;\">Actual Length of Period WITHOUT Premium Payment</td>"
            + "<td>"+rcso+"</td>"                
            + "</tr>";
```

I also investigated the data I am getting and there were no ampersand(&) in any form.
So puzzled with this. I also search through my code if there are any ampersand(&) but I found nothing.

This is the SQL data

```
PARTNER,NAME_FIRST,NAMEMIDDLE,NAME_LAST,ZZSUFFIX,FULLNAME,AGENCY_NAME,AGENCY_ADDRESS,AGENCY

_BP_NUMBER,BDAY,BIRTHDATE,IDNO,CRN,POLICY_TYPE,MEM_ADDRESS,TOTAL_LENGTH_OF_SERVICE,INSOBJECT,POLICY_NUMBER,PERSONAL_SHARE,GOV_SHARE,EC_LIFE,PS_LIFE_INTEREST,GS_LIFE_INTEREST,PS_RET_INTEREST,GS_RET_INTEREST,EC_INTEREST,PROD_TYPE,DATA_LOAN_GRANTED,CONTRACT,GROSS,TOT_AMORT,TOT_REPAYMENT,OB_PRINCIPAL,INT_SUR,OB_TOT,LEAVE_WITHOUT_PAY,ACTUAL_LENGTH_OF_SERVICE,RCS,ACT_LNGTH_SRV_WITHOUT
'2000133249','NERA','A','GALAN',,'NERA A GALAN ','BICOL UNIV COLLEGE OF NURSING','LEGASPI CITY  ALBAY','1000000853','1969-03-25','March 25, 1969','69032501435','006000188531','COMPULSORY','PUROK 4 ROVER SUBD TUGOS CITY OF SORSOGON SORSOGON',,'00000010000003138060','CM00003730951',13170.24,17560.32,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,,,,,,,,,,0E-8,,0E-8,
```

Comment: I can't see any errors in your html. How are you converting this to pdf? Please post your code so we can have a look

Comment: Have a look at the complete `html` variable in the debugger or log it... and log `html.contains("&")` for example.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite possibly in `var1`, `var2`, `var3` or `var4`. (For example, it might be a business name of "Smith & Jones". We don't know what's in those variables given their overly-generic names, of course.)

This is why you should build up XML using an XML API, which can perform any appropriate escaping for you. It's fundamentally the same mistake as using string concatenation to build a SQL statement including user input instead of using parameterized SQL - it's just in a slightly different form.

Comment: XML API? How should I?

Comment: I am about to generate 1000 pdfs. But in 573rd, I am getting that error.

Comment: @user2510841: Well which XML API have you the most experience with? There are plenty available. If you haven't used any before, look around, pick one, and ask a *specific* question if you run into problems.

Comment: @user2510841: So look at the variable values for that particular PDf - I bet one of them has an `&` in.

Comment: I posted the content of my variables. Please take a look.

Comment: Ill chec my sql statement.

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with XML API. I am just using this: ` renderer.getSharedContext().setReplacedElementFactory(new MediaReplacedElementFactory(renderer.getSharedContext().getReplacedElementFactory()));
        renderer.setDocumentFromString(html);`

Comment: @user2510841: No, my point is that you should build up the XML element by element.

Comment: @user2510841 did we get the solution? I mean did you do anything to permanently get rid this of this issue. I am facing the same issue with few special characters while generating the PDF.